# Python Telegram bot auto send message every interval

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I have the following code to send message using a bot. But how can i send this message every 1hour? I need help please. Thank you.

```
import requests
import time
jokes = ['TEXT']

for joke in jokes:
   base_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<<token>>/sendMessage?chat_id= CHATID&text=" {}"'.format(joke)
   requests.get(base_url
   time.sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple loop handler for you.

```
import threading
import time
class loop:
    def wait(self, seconds):
        # This makes sure that when self.running is false it will instantly stop
        for a in range(seconds):
            if self.running:
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                break

    def run(self, seconds):
        while self.running:
            # Runs function
            self.function()
            self.wait(seconds)

    def __init__(self, seconds, function):
        self.running = True
        self.function = function
        # Starts new thread instead of running it in the main thread
        # is because so it will not block other code
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=(seconds,))
        self.thread.start()
```

You can use it like this:

```
import requests
import random
def sendJoke():
    # Gets random joke instead of looping through all of the jokes
    randomJoke = jokes[random.randrange(len(jokes))]
    base_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<<token>>/sendMessage?chat_id= CHATID&text=" {}"'.format(randomJoke)
    requests.get(base_url)
# loop(seconds, function)
a = loop(3600, sendJoke)
```

You can stop it anytime by:

```
a.running = False
```